# How do I force a peer review for my edit when I already have editing privileges?

Tags: discussion, editing, peer-review

How do I force my edit through the peer review system (for example, when I'm not sure if I did it right) when I already have editing privileges?

It seems like creating peer review requests is a rare tricky feature that becomes unavailable after reputation has increased sufficiently.

Comment: Why do you think reviewers know more about the topic than you do?

Comment: Reviewer may know more about "it is appropriate edit or not?" (independently on topic). It is like `I suggest the question is actually like this ..... Just click "accept edit" if it really so.`. Like a comment to the question, but more suited for improving it. Using RCS terms it is like "This is my patch, decide to apply it or not".

Comment: Keep in mind, somebody can always revert the edit if for some reason it didn't work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No can do. We trust you to make your own edits now!

If you're ever not quite sure, err on the side of caution. As long as you respect the intentions of the original author, you should be good. You're always welcome to ask people in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) for advice before making your edit.

Comment: So no need to create special low-priv account for "unsure" edits.

Comment: No, please do not do that.